# Сколько переменных надо для подсчёта суммы?

Tags: python-3.x

> Дано несколько чисел. Вычислите их сумму. Сначала вводите количество чисел N. затем вводится ровно N целых
>   чисел.

Какое наименьшее число переменных нужно для решения этой задачи?

```
i=int(input())
a=i*int(input())
z=0
for i in range(a,a-1):
    z+=a
print(z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Ноль.** Количество сразу использовать в качестве верхней границы, затем map, который читает остальное, потом сумму вывести.

Код с `range` работает, но кроме суммы выводит элементы range.
http://ideone.com/3uuq1X

```
print(sum(map(int, map(input, range(int(input()))))))
```

Но вместо range можно использовать список из нужного числа пустых строк.
http://ideone.com/kJ4A6W

```
print(sum(map(int, map(input, [''] * int(input())))))
```

Comment: жесть, ну зачем так сразу пугать человека =) к тому же скорее всего его преподаватель этот ответ не оценит, или еще хуже - не поймет =(

Comment: @rdorn, _"Какое наименьшее число переменных нужно для решения этой задачи?"_ - вероятно, любое другое количество не будет наименьшим?

Comment: всё понял спасибо.

Comment: @sigmon123, в таком случае надо принять ответ.

Comment: Ответ принят ✓ 
Проверяй

Comment: @sigmon123, нажми на зелёную галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: @sigmon123, уточнил ответ. А то `map` на `range` выводит сами индексы.

Comment: @Qwertiy по сути это для начинающих сайт, и реализация должна быть в for (не нашёл где в лс тебе скинуть ссылку) [ссылка](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/for_loop/problems/sum_of_n_numbers/)

Comment: а что считать переменной? вот например более чем уверен что внутри map будут все N чисел сохранены, а если ручками писать то хватит 3 чисел.

Comment: @pavel `Переменная (программирование) — поименованная, либо адресуемая иным способом область памяти, адрес которой можно использовать для осуществления доступа к данным и изменять значение в ходе выполнения программы.` Нет имени - нет переменной. Все просто.

Comment: @sigmon123, вопрос ведь не как решить, а какое минимальное число переменных нужно. for использует переменную, этот вариант - нет. Значит, вариант с for не минимален по числу переменных.

Comment: Можно просто до конца ввода читать, проигнорировав первую строчку с N: `next(sys.stdin); print(sum(map(int, sys.stdin)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 0
for i in range(int(input())):
    s += int(input())
print(s)
```

[3 часа решал, ответ оказался на гит хабе , кек](https://github.com/pythontutor/pythontutor-ru/issues/138)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/76667)

Comment: @Streletz, код в ответе и есть ответ. Чем тебе ссылка помешала?